# Sender Device's ID in GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I have below script in my server script for my GCM application which I have obtained from a tutorial on GCM application.

```
   $fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => array( $registrationIDs ),
            'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
            );

   $headers = array( 
                'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );


  // Open connection
  $ch = curl_init();
```

NB: $registrationIDs is the ID for the device to which the message is to be delivered.

I have noted that on the above script, there is no place where I add the sender device's ID, probably the reason my script does not deliver messages for the chat.Please help me know how i should go about the same.Thanks fellow coders

Comment: Sender Id is for client side not for server side i guess

Comment: @Clairvoyant i thought the chat needs to carry both the sender and the recipients ID along the message?

Comment: There's a different reason for why your messages aren't delivered. Check your logs and server responses. You could run a cURL command from terminal (check the curl example [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)) to quickly check the response. Like @Clairvoyant said, the sender ID is only needed on the client side.